# Is there an algorithm for writing a number as a sum of three squares?

Tags: nt.number-theory

By Gauss's Theorem, every positive integer $n$ is a sum of three triangular numbers; 
these are numbers of the form $\frac{m(m+1)}2$. Clearly
$$ n = \frac{m_1^2+m_1}2 + \frac{m_2^2+m_2}2 + \frac{m_3^2+m_3}2, $$
so multiplying through by $4$ and completing the squares gives
$$ 8n+3 = (2m_1+1)^2 + (2m_2+1)^2 + (2m_3+1)^2. $$
Thus writing $n$ as a sum of three triangular numbers is equivalent to writing $8n+3$ as a sum of three (necessarily odd) squares.

My question is;

*Is there an algorithm for writing a positive integer as a sum of three squares?*

Comment: I find the question's wording is pretty bad.

Comment: In general, there will be lots of ways to represent a given integer as the sum of three triangular numbers. I don't think any one of them has a distinguished formula.

Comment: There is a lot of structure behind representations of sums of three squares. In an article that I don't yet understand, Simerka seems to have found a connection between writing numbers in different ways as sums of three squares and factoring this number. And writing
$n$ as a sum of three triangular numbers is equivalent to writing $8n+3$ as a sum of three squares.

Comment: This wording is better: taking back my downvote accordingly! Thanks!

Comment: A bit confusing, Simerka lived a long time ago, the recent item is a history/overview by Franz, see http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0282 Meanwhile, what is quite definitely in Grosswald's book is the relation of number of representations as three squares to certain classnumbers, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/3596/is-there-a-simple-way-to-compute-the-number-of-ways-to-write-a-positive-integer-a/22655#22655  

Comment: For the NUMBER of representations, check out the cool paper of Ono, Robins, and Wahl, where they write the generating function for all polygonal numbers.

Comment: The arxive article is about Simerka's invention of a factoring algorithm using the class group of quadratic forms. He also has written an article on Legendre's work on the sums of three squares
and trinary forms  in which he connects sums of three squares with factoring integers in a way I do not yet understand. All I'm saying is that the question has some merit. There is also a hint at the factorization of integers in the algorithm presented in Will's link.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/q/104322/12357

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/483101/14578

Comment: See last post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/913957/decomposition-into-three-squares/3147621#3147621 It works for certain numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A representation of $n$ as a sum of three triangular numbers is equivalent to representing $8n+3$ as a sum of three odd squares. The question of computing representations as a sum of three squares has been much discussed here, see [Efficient computation of integer representation as a sum of three squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104322/efficient-computation-of-integer-representation-as-sum-of-three-squares)

Answer (score 12):

This problem is discussed in my paper with Rabin, Randomized algorithms in number theory,
Commun. Pure Appl. Math. 39, 1985, S239 - S256.  We give an algorithm that, assuming a couple of reasonable conjectures, will produce a representation as a sum of three squares in random polynomial time.

Comment: Is it reasonable in practice? (I actually need to compute this :)

Comment: Yes, it works very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

One point that I do not see in the answer to which Igor links is size. Your target number is some $k \equiv 3 \pmod 8.$ So we take some odd $z$ and find out whether $k - z^2$ is the sum of two squares by factoring. My advice is to take $z$ as large as possible to begin, the decrease $z$ by 2 at each failure. There are two reasons for this.

First, the numbers $j \equiv 2 \pmod 8$ that actually are the sum of two squares are more frequent the smaller the approximate size of $j.$ Combining all congruence classes $\pmod 8,$ the number of integers up to some real positive $x$ is about  $$  \frac{0.7642 \; x}{\sqrt{\log x}}, $$ so they get less frequent near $x$ as $x$ gets bigger.

Second, deciding whether $k-z^2$ is the sum of two squares is just factoring, and factoring is quicker for smaller numbers: powers of $2$ are irrelevant, any positive integer $j$ is the sum of two squares if and only if, when factoring $j,$ the exponent of any prime divisor $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ is even. Indeed, if there are any such, what you actually do is divide out all the appropriate $q^{2a}$ to arrive at a smaller number $j_0,$ write that as $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = j_0$ by solving that for each remaining prime power $p^w$ with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ which involves finding a square root of $-1 \pmod p$ and then screwing around. Combining pieces comes from
$$ (a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ad-bc)^2 + (ac + bd)^2.    $$ Oh, when yopu are done with $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = j_0,$ you put back each $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ with $(q^a x_0)^2 + (q^a y_0)^2 = q^{2a} j_0.$

Well, there is more to it, as you can see. But start with large $z.$ Size Matters.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that there is a representation with z^2 being, say 7/8 of n or larger?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.10.21

Comment: @Gerhard, I don't think there are any non-trivial guarantees, so the worst case behavior of starting with $z$ as large as possible is worse than the best case behavior of starting with $z$ small. Now that you mention it, at the cost of roughly constant slowdown, do two or three strategies at once (regarding the size of $z$) and hope for the best. But, all we know for sure is that, if $z$ is the largest, then $z^2$ is at least $1/3$ of the number. So that is one simple strategy, start $z$ there and increase.  

Comment: Now for the flip side: are there any examples known where there is no representation with z especially large?  Gerhard "May Ask About Distribution Next" Paseman, 2012.10.21

Comment: @Gerhard, back from grocery shopping. I don't know that anyone has collected such examples, but i would expect them to get less frequent as the number gets large, as long as the number is not divisible by 4. So there would be no difficulty on a home computer picking out a range, say 1 to 1,000,000, run a triple loop in C, and report back when all $z$ are forced close to the minimum. As the target numbers get large the  number of representations grow, so I would expect the odds of at least one  solution with large $z$ to grow by "equidistribution," which goes back to Linnik.