# Listing all solutions to $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 $ with integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, quadratic-forms

I would like to list **all** ways of writing $n$ as the sum of 3 squares.  This is slightly different from finding just one:

- [Is there an algorithm for writing a number as a sum of three squares?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110239/)
- [Efficient computation of integer representation as a sum of three squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104322/)
- [Rabin and Shallit Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483101/rabin-and-shallit-algorithm)

My current implementation is the naive one which runs in $O(n^{3/2})$  time: Write all numbers $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ with

- $x < \sqrt{n}$
- $y < \sqrt{n - x^2}$
- $z < \sqrt{n - x^2 - y^2}$

Perhaps there is a more efficient way using [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) or matrices or something?

## Finding All Representations

The linked questions efficiently compute **one** representation $n = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.  However, I am hoping to find a complete list of **all** representations and I would like to know if we can do any better than the naïve algorithm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an algorithm for writing a number as a sum of three squares?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110239/is-there-an-algorithm-for-writing-a-number-as-a-sum-of-three-squares)

Comment: Duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110239/is-there-an-algorithm-for-writing-a-number-as-a-sum-of-three-squares

Comment: @IgorRivin Can the algorithm for finding **one** representation be turned into an algorithm for finding **all** representations?

Comment: A fair point, so the question is not quite a duplicate.

Comment: Somewhat less naive is to loop over $x < \sqrt{n}$.  For each 
$m = n - x^2$ you then want to find all representations $m = y^2 + z^2$, which can be obtained by factoring $m$ over the Gaussian integers.  I'm pretty sure we don't know the true complexity of that (not even of factoring over the integers), but it's certainly $o(m)$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It sounds like an improvement but I compute $ \sum \sqrt{n - x^2} \approx \mathrm{Area}(\circ) = O( n) $ as an estimate of the runtime.  Not that I am any kind of expert.

Answer (score 7):

The number of representation can be as big as $\sqrt{n},$ so this is a lower bound on the complexity of any algorithm. Now, the algorithm is to iterate through all $k\leq \sqrt{n},$ and try to represent $n-k^2$ as a sum of squares (in all possible ways). This is equivalent to factoring, so the complexity will be not that bad above optimal (factoring is "hard", but not so hard compared to $\sqrt{n},$ indeed, this algorithm runs in time $O(n^{1/2 + \epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0.$)

Comment: For each of the numbers $k < \sqrt{n}$ I can factor $n - k^2$ which I can do in $\sqrt{n}$ time, so the total run time is $\sqrt{n} \times \sqrt{n} = n$.

Comment: @johnmangual it's a lot better than that, see the edited version.

Comment: The factorization step takes $log(n)$ time or something ?

Comment: @johnmangual http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Integer_factorization#/Difficulty_and_complexity